# Error setting vscode as difftool and mergetool in windows

Tags: git, difftool

I am getting the below error when I try to use merge tool in git.

```
git config option merge.tool set to unknown tool: code
Resetting to default...

This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured.
See 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare smerge emerge vimdiff nvimdiff
```

I want to use vscode as difftool and merge tool.

Here is my config file

```
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait $MERGED
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

How can I configure vscode as my difftool and mergetool?

Comment: Does running `code --help` from the command line work? Also, are you using Git Bash on Windows, cmd.exe, PowerShell or a different OS entirely?

Comment: Git bash on windows, “code” on command line opens vscode @ElderFuthark

Comment: I tested your config on Git bash (2.21.0.windows.1) and it worked flawlessly. Can you please edit your question to include the output of `code --help` and `git mergetool --tool-help`?

Answer (score 0):

> Git bash on windows, “code” on command line opens vscod

That means `code` is in your `%PATH%`/`$PATH`.

If "'`merge.tool`' is not configured.", that means you are running the Git session with a different account than the one where code, on command-line, work.

In that problematic session, try:

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope|grep merge
```

Check if `merge.tool` is indeed set.